# How to remove a field from params[:something]

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My registration form, which is a form for the Users model, takes a string value for company. However, I have just made a change such that users belongs_to companies. Therefore, I need to pass an object of Company to the Users model.

I want to use the string value from the form to obtain the an object of Company:

```
@user.company = Company.find_by_name(params[:company])
```

I believe the above works, however the form is passing the :company (which is string) into the model when I call:

```
@user = User.new(params[:user])
```

Therefore, I want to know (and cannot find how) to remove the :company param before passing it to the User model.

Answer (score 244, accepted):

**Rails 4/5 - edited answer**
(see comments)

Since this question was written newer versions of Rails have added the [extract!](https://apidock.com/rails/Hash/extract%21) and [except](https://apidock.com/rails/Hash/except) eg:

```
new_params = params.except[the one I wish to remove]
```

This is a safer way to 'grab' all the params you need into a copy WITHOUT destroying the original passed in params (which is NOT a good thing to do as it will make debugging and maintenance of your code very hard over time).

Or you could just pass directly without copying eg:

```
@person.update(params[:person].except(:admin))
```

The `extract!` (has the ! bang operator) will modify the original so use with more care!

**Original Answer**

You can remove a key/value pair from a Hash using `Hash#delete`:

```
params.delete :company
```

If it's contained in params[:user], then you'd use this:

```
params[:user].delete :company
```

Comment: This is great, but should we do it inside the controller? Seems like the controller knows too much about the view if we do that.

Comment: I am using Rails 4.0, and `model_params.delete :key_name` doesn't work - any idea why?

Comment: deleting from the params hash is a very BAD IDEA. confuses people easily during debugging etc... use a custom hash that you pass to assign attributes, e.g. use ```assin_params = params.dup.delete(:company)```. never delete from params directly

Comment: i meant ```assign_params = params.dup; assign_params.delete(:company)```

Comment: @Zorayr I had the same issue. For me it was because my `model_params` was a function, which pulled the relevant params from `params`. So when you `delete` from `model_params` you're really just deleting from the hash that `model_params` returns.

Comment: user_params is a method, so when you do user_params.delete(:this_param), it computes the right hash, but any subsequent call to user_params will recompute the hash from scratch. This is why @Gaul said it is a bad idea. In Rails 5 you now have params.except method and also extract!

Comment: @Gaul After duplicating the hash params and modifying the copy, how can I pass the new hash params to the controller. Actually I intercept in my UPDATE method I thinks there is where I have to delete but how can I send the new hash params? I just let the execution go on or what?

Answer (score 93):

You should probably be using hash.except

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  def explore_session_params
    params[:explore_session].except(:account_id, :creator)
  end
end
```

It accomplishes 2 things: allows you to exclude more than 1 key at a time, and doesn't modify the original hash.

Comment: Rails 4 ActionController::Parameters inherited Hash, so except or extract! would work, In Rails 5, it has [except](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-except) and extract! methods defined in ActionController::Parameters itself

Comment: I actually have this hash params in the UPDATE method. How can I except the ones who has `"-1"` as the key.

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "_method"=>"patch",
 "authenticity_token"=>"VtY...",
 "brochure"=>
  {"title"=>"Hello world",
   "profilings_attributes"=>
    {"-1"=>{"member_profile_id"=>"3"},
     "0"=>{"percentage"=>"10.0", "description"=>"Some description!", "_destroy"=>"false", "id"=>"10"},
     "1"=>{...}},
   "sponsorings_attributes"=>
    {"-1"=>{"sponsor_id"=>"2"},
     "0"=>{"brochure_id"=>"1", "_destroy"=>"false", "id"=>"3"},
     "1"=>{...}},
 "commit"=>"Guardar",
 "id"=>"1"}

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to achieve this is using [`strong_params`](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html)

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
  end

  private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :age)
  end
end
```

This way you have more control over which params should be passed to model

Answer (score 1):

```
respond_to do |format|
  if params[:company].present?
    format.html { redirect_to(:controller => :shopping, :action => :index) }
  else
    format.html
  end
end
```

this will remove params from the url

Answer (score 1):

#### Rails 5+: Use the handy `extract!` method with strong params!

The `extract!` method removes the desired variable from the Parameters object ([docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v7.0.2.3/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-extract-21)) and returns a new ActionController::Parameters object. This allows you to handle params properly (i.e. with strong params) and deal with the extracted variable separately.

##### Example:

```rb
# Request { user: { company: 'a', name: 'b', age: 100 } }

# this line removes company from params
company = params.require(:user).extract!(:company)

# note: the value of the new variable `company` is { company: 'a' }
# since extract! returns an instance of ActionController::Parameters

# we permit :name and :age, and receive no errors or warnings since 
# company has been removed from params
params.require(:user).permit(:name, :age)

# if desired, we could use the extracted variable as the question indicates
@company = Company.find_by_name(company.require(:company))
```

##### Full example in controller

Of course, we could wrap this up in a handy method in our controller:

```rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_user, only: [:create]

  def create
    # ...
    @user.save
  end

  def set_user
    company = params.require(:user).extract!(:company)
    @user = User.new(params.require(:user).permit(:name, :age))
    @user.company = Company.find_by_name(company.require(:company))
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

To be possible to delete you can do a **memo**:

```
def parameters
  @parameters ||= params.require(:root).permit(:foo, :bar)
end
```

Now you can do:

```
parameteres.delete(:bar)
```

```
parameters
=> <ActionController::Parameters {"foo" => "foo"} permitted: true>
```