# Get raw parameter data in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parameters

I have a ruby on rails api where I want to sign my request data by appending a hashed version of all passed in parameters to the request and rebuild this one at the server side as well to validate the integrity of the requests.

When I simply use the `params` method in the controller I have different parameters (e.g. for an `update`-method which is specified by this:

```
put 'login' => 'login#update'
```

I get as parameters on the server:

```
{"timestamp"=>"1399562324118", "secured"=>"xxx", 
 "login"=>{"timestamp"=>"1399562324118", "secured"=>"xxx"}}
```

although I only send the request from the client with

```
{"timestamp"=>"1399562324118", "secured"=>"xxx"}
```

Does any one have an idea how to get rid of this `"login"` parameter in the params list in a generic way? I do not want to exclude this for every single request of my api.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: you can delete things from the params hash, see [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5150676/how-to-remove-a-field-from-paramssomething](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5150676/how-to-remove-a-field-from-paramssomething)

Comment: Yes, but this is no generic way. Because I have to do this for every generated parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the Rails Edge guide on ActionController:

"If you've turned on config.wrap_parameters in your initializer or calling wrap_parameters in your controller, you can safely omit the root element in the JSON parameter"

See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#json-parameters